# Open two copies of the same notebook

Tags: front-end, notebooks, editing

Is there a way to open one notebook in two (or more) different windows? This can be helpful when working with a long notebook and one wants to edit one part of it while looking at a different part. Otherwise, you have to jump back and forth...

**Edit:** Per @Guillochon comment, splitting the window where the notebook is open is indeed a nice option.

**Edit 2**: Having a secondary "read-only" window can also be a nice compromise.

Comment: I like this question.  I would expect the behavior to mirror (clone) the Notebook, such that a change in one is made to the other; optionally only one would be directly editable.  I don't know how to do this but I'd like to find out.

Comment: Isn't @Dror just asking for a split-screen window? Almost all modern text editors have that feature...

Comment: @Guillochon Yes, but the mathematica interface is not a modern text editor:) All modern text editors have tab-indent as well, but try doing that in the notebook interface. I guess using Workbench is always an option, although I never got used to it...

Comment: I asked this split screen question to Wolfram in 1994! He tried and convince me I didn't need it.

Comment: Deleting my comments, since they don't apply to a window split.

Comment: @chris And what arguments did Wolfram give you?

Comment: Tell us what you want and we ll explain to you why you don't need it! :-) The answer bellow works fine for me though.

Comment: If anyone is still interested, I gave an answer for copies where either are editable [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120799/41227).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a rather unsophisticated approach. The code below creates a toolbar in the current notebook, with buttons to create, refresh and close a replica notebook. The replica is given a gray background and cannot be edited or evaluated.

I tried to do something with `Dynamic` to automatically refresh the replica notebook, but without success.

### Update

Here is a neater implementation. The code below creates a palette (which can be installed using the menu: Palettes/Install Palette) containing a single button to create a duplicate of the active notebook. The update button for the duplicate is now located in the duplicate itself, leaving the original notebook unchanged. The duplicate is closed using the normal window close button, but it has `"ClosingSaveDialog"` set to `False` so you won't get a save prompt.

```
CreatePalette[Button["Duplicate Active Notebook",
   NotebookPut[NotebookGet[InputNotebook[]] /. 
   {Rule[DockedCells, _] :> Sequence[], 
    Rule[WindowMargins, _] :> Rule[WindowMargins, {{0, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}], 
    Cell[x___] :> Cell[x, Evaluatable -> False]}, 
    Background -> GrayLevel[0.95], Editable -> False, "ClosingSaveDialog" -> False, 
    DockedCells -> With[{sourcenb = InputNotebook[]}, 
      Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[Button["Update", 
          SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Notebook]; 
          NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], 
           NotebookGet[sourcenb] /. Cell[x___] :> Cell[x, Evaluatable -> False]]]]],
       "DockedCell", CellContext -> Cell]],
    WindowTitle -> "Duplicate of " <> AbsoluteOptions[InputNotebook[], WindowTitle][[1, 2]]];
   SetSelectedNotebook[InputNotebook[]]], WindowTitle -> "Duplicate"];
```

Comment: +1 Great idea. I did notice that syntax highlighting doesn't work, which is a big minus.

Comment: @Ajasja: That's not quite right; There is some degree of highlighting. For example internal variables of modules - do get colored in green.

Comment: @SimonWoods: The `Close toolbar` doesn't work for me - I get `SetOptions::optnf: DockedCells is not a known option for thisnb. >>` error. Any idea?

Comment: @Dror Well most of the built in functions are not highlighted. [example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5C3ro.png), which makes the code really hard to read. This is probably realted to the `Evaluator -> None` option. Setting it to `Evaluator -> "Local"` fixes the problem (but not in a general way since local may not exist)

Comment: @Ajasja, I've replaced the `Evaluator->None` option with explicit `Evaluator->False` options in each cell, so the syntax highlighting should now work.

Comment: @Dror, I've replaced `thisnb` with explicit references to `EvaluationNotebook[]` so hopefully that error has gone away.

Comment: Instead of `Dynamic`, you could set up the "Refresh replica" function to trigger on specific keystrokes or mouse clicks using `NotebookEventActions`.

Comment: @dws, the way I've done it, the replica notebook will scroll to the bottom every time it is refreshed, so I thought it should only happen when explicity requested. There's also a performance issue - I copy the entire notebook contents on refresh so it could be a slow process for large notebooks.

Comment: @SimonWoods Is there a way to make your hack into a global one? That is, I want to be able to evaluate `duplicate[]` for instance in a notebook which doesn't contain your code snippet. Is it possible?

Comment: @Dror, see update.

Comment: @SimonWoods: That looks great! I failed to install it as a palette. I tried both using the "Install Palette" menu and manually copying the notebook where I saved the snippet to `~/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Palettes`- I managed to have a new palette item, but when clicking it, it simply opens the notebook. Can you please add specific instructions how to install it?

Comment: @Dror, It sounds like you have installed the notebook containing the `CreatePalette` code, rather than the palette it creates. Open a fresh notebook, paste my code into it and execute it. This should create a palette window titled "Duplicate" at the top right of the screen. You can now close the notebook window - you don't need to save it, the code has done its job. Now go to Palettes/Install Palette on the menu, select "Duplicate" as the Source and provide an install name (e.g. Duplicate). Then click Finish. You should now have the new item in the Palette menu.

Comment: I came back to this answer from a Wolfram Community post and decided to give it a shot to tweak this to make it automatic. [Care to give it a shot](http://pastebin.com/de19FA87)? I haven't tested it much and we know how weird Dynamic can be

Comment: @Rojo, looks good but `Cells` is new in version 9, which I don't have yet :-(

Comment: @Rojo That is fantastic! I love it. A useful addition would be to add a "jump to" feature. So a Ctrl-click (or whatever combination) on a cell in the master notebook will automatically take you to the corresponding cell in the duplicate. ``Developer`CellInformation`` might come in handy here

Comment: +1  Any way to make this work to display one screen environment's "Screen Environment" from another?  I would like to edit the notebook in a window using the "Working" environment and simultaneously view the "SlideShow" environment.  Manually editing the setting in the new window does not seem to work in 10.3.0, nor does creating the slideshow and then changing the environment in the original window.

Comment: Very useful.  Many thanks!

Comment: This is great, thank you!