# A palette of accumulated expertise

Tags: palettes

I've been trying to put together a palette of useful functionality garnered from this site.  There is useful stuff scattered all over the place, for example:

- [Post an image](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes)
- [Copy code](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/how-can-i-easily-copy-mathematica-code-for-use-with-this-site-we-have-a-palett)
- [Duplicate a notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9280/open-two-copies-of-the-same-notebook)
- [Paste a table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9010/427)

As an ugly, yet functional, way of putting them together, I have something like:

```
CreatePalette[Column[{
    OpenerView[{"Duplicate Active Notebook", duplicating}, True],
    OpenerView[{"Pasting a table", pasting}, True],
    OpenerView[{"Copy for StackExchange", copyForStackExchange}, True]
    (* etc *)
    }],
  WindowTitle -> "mathematica.stackexchange.com"];
```

where the definitions inside each `OpenerView` are slight modifications of the code from the above links.  (Usually just stripping off any existing palette stuff is all that is required.  I did find that a single button seemed to require `ImageSize -> Automatic` so it would display properly.)

So the question is, what else can I add to this?

**Are there any procedures *you* use regularly that are suitable for a palette?**  Things that have made your mathematica experience easier and more productive?
**Is there any enlightening information that could be continually displayed on a palette?**  E.g. progress bars, memory usage, cursor position?
**Are there any tips and hints for beginners that could be nicely presented on a palette?**

Comment: This looks a bit like [our famous toolbag question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4198961/615464) on SO/Mathematica. You'll find contributions of many of the top users there. It is closed though, as questions like these and yours not really adhere to the rules for admissible questions.

Comment: I like the question (+1) but it must be community wiki.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Agree ...  but we should find a place to collaborate on these. If we can't find another way, I vote for bending the rules somewhat.

Comment: @belisarius i agree

Answer (score 19):

I used to think that Mathematica was an incorrigible memory hog until I visited this site and discovered the wonders of `$HistoryLength`.  This seems to be a common complaint that is easily remedied.  Below is a scattering of buttons that show the current value and allow it to be easily changed:

```
historyLengthButtons := Grid[{Dynamic[Button[#, $HistoryLength = #, Background -> 
   If[$HistoryLength == #, Yellow, Automatic]]] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, Infinity}
 }, Spacings -> 1]
```

[image: 1]

**Edit**

A memory usage graph:

```
memoryInUse = ConstantArray[MemoryInUse[], 60];
frontEndInUse = ConstantArray[MemoryInUse[$FrontEnd], 60];
RunScheduledTask[
  memoryInUse = Append[Rest@memoryInUse, MemoryInUse[]];
  frontEndInUse = Append[Rest@frontEndInUse, MemoryInUse[$FrontEnd]];
, 5];

memoryUsagePlot := Dynamic[Grid[{{Overlay[{
  ListPlot[memoryInUse, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5,
    Axes -> False, Background -> Black, PlotStyle -> Green, ImageSize -> Small,
    GridLines -> {12 (Range[6] - 1), None}, GridLinesStyle -> Darker@Gray],
  ListPlot[frontEndInUse, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5,
    Axes -> False, Background -> None, PlotStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> Small]
   }],
 Style["Kernel", Darker@Green], NumberForm[N[Last[memoryInUse]/10^6], {9, 2}], "MB"},
 {SpanFromAbove,
 Style["Front End", Darker@Red], NumberForm[N[Last[frontEndInUse]/10^6], {9, 2}], "MB"
 }}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]]
```

As per Silvia's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7088467/935879), a memory profile:

```
ClearAll[myByteCount]; 
myByteCount[symbolName_String] := 
  Quiet@Replace[ToHeldExpression[symbolName], 
  Hold[x__] :> If[MemberQ[Attributes[x], Protected | ReadProtected], 
  Sequence @@ {}, {ByteCount[Through[{OwnValues, DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, 
  DefaultValues, FormatValues, NValues}[Unevaluated@x, Sort -> False]]], symbolName}]];

memoryProfileButton := 
  Button["Memory profile", CreateDocument[
  Style[With[{listing = myByteCount /@ Names[]}, 
  Labeled[Grid[Reverse@Take[Sort[listing], -100], Frame -> True, Alignment -> Left], 
  Column[{Style["ByteCount for symbols without attributes Protected and" <>
  "ReadProtected in all contexts", 16, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
  Style[Row@{"Total: ", Total[listing[[All, 1]]], " bytes for ",
  Length[listing], " symbols"}, Bold]}, Center, 1.5], Top]],
  ShowStringCharacters -> False], WindowSelected -> True, 
  WindowTitle -> "Memory profile"], ImageSize -> Automatic]
```

Put it all in one section:

```
OpenerView[{"Memory", 
  Column[{historyLengthButtons, memoryProfileButton, memoryUsagePlot}]}, True]
```

[image: memory]

Comment: I found [this memory profile function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7088467/935879) very useful.

Comment: this is amazing, thank you